# vgrant up fails with "unknown configuration section 'version'"

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

```
vagrant up   

Bringing machine 'glialvid' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

Vagrant:
* Unknown configuration section 'version'.
```

System environment

```
System: OS X Yosemite v 10.10.1
VirtualBox: 4.3.20
Vagrant: 1.6.5
Ansible: 1.8.1
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Paste the content of `Vagrantfile` for checking

Answer (score 7):

Install the following plugins:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant_box_version
```

and

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-triggers
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the Virtual machine with VirtualBox and check the virtual machine settings .. try to fix the warnings or errors in the settings.

You will find the boxes in this path  `~/.vagrant.d/boxes`

Good luck.

I hope this could help!

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, you may  need something like this in begin of `Vagrantfile`:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
```